# AWS Lambda - using pickle creates timeout

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-lambda

I have a python 2.7 lambda function that I've uploaded to AWS through zip file. It hangs on a call to load a file using cpickle (the file is available in the local directory uploaded in the zip file).

This works fine on my machine, and I've even tried printing out a few lines of the pickled file just to make sure it's actually able to find the file, and they look fine.

Here's the code, any ideas?

```
import cPickle as pickle
import os

def chooseNextWord(sentence):
    pkl_file = open('bigrams.pkl', 'rb')
    bigrams = pickle.load(pkl_file)
    return sentence


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    return chooseNextWord("hello")
```

If I comment out the pickle.load, everything runs and I can read line by line from the file normally, using pkl_file.readline().

Comment: It looks like this was a memory issue. I upped the allocated memory for the lambda function and everything ran fine.

Comment: How much RAM did you give the lambda to consume?

Comment: I went from 128 to 256mb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution that I figured out shortly after posting this question, increase the available memory for the lambda function. The object I was loading into memory was too large. The timeout was misleading as an error.

Comment: yeah you need to watch things like this with Lambda, for example using the Node MySQL client and not closing the connection when the Lamdba ends will also result in a timeout.

Answer (score 0):

There is a issue in your code not aws lambda. Issue is here

```
pickle.load("filename")
```

pickle.load takes filename as argument not file descriptor.
open('bigrams.pkl', 'rb') return a file descriptor.
so in your case

```
def chooseNextWord(sentence):
    bigrams = pickle.load('bigrams.pkl')
    return sentence
```

this might work for you